# how to configure simply android studio to run JUnit tests

Tags: java, android, junit, android-studio

I'm running JUnit tests with Android studio, it's great.

In order to do so, I had to fight a bit and add the following to the VM options, because adding junit 4.12 to the *Dependencies* of the *Application* in the *Project Structure* did not work.

My question is : why, and am I doing something wrong ?

`-ea -classpath "C:\Users\obfuscated\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;D:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar;D:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\classes\test\debug;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\classes\debug;C:\Users\obfuscated\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.objenesis\objenesis\1.0\9b473564e792c2bdf1449da1f0b1b5bff9805704\objenesis-1.0.jar;C:\Users\obfuscated\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\libs\internal_impl-21.0.3.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\classes.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\res;D:\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v13\21.0.2\libs\internal_impl-21.0.2.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v13\21.0.2\classes.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v13\21.0.2\res;C:\Users\obfuscated\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-core\1.9.5\c3264abeea62c4d2f367e21484fbb40c7e256393\mockito-core-1.9.5.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\cardview-v7\21.0.2\res;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\cardview-v7\21.0.2\classes.jar;D:\Android\projets\AndroidStudioProjects\ElevationDrag\Application\build\intermediates\mockable-android-21.jar"`

If I follow instructions given [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) I find myself with the following error :

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:173)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code -3
```

Answer (score 0):

Android class has to be run in a device or emulator. If not you need some means to mock the android.jar

Please take a look at:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support
or
http://robolectric.org/

Comment: @Yu Han: If you read carefully my question, you'll find that I already refer to the link you've given. I may be doing something wrong. I have found a workaround, so it's OK. But I prefer understanding to belief, hence my question.